# fixing communication port errors

Tags: serial

the communication port (com11) is yellowed with exclamation marks in device manager and I am unable to run arduino on my computer. how to get rid of the yellow exclamation mark on the com 11?

Comment: I guess you are using Windows? You might need to install the correct driver. Do you have a genuine Arduino, or one of the cheap clones? (They use different USB to Serial chips)

Comment: how do I know if it is genuine or clone in the first place?

Comment: It's written on it or on the box it came in.

Comment: Provide a link to the actual thing you bought.